# How do I use a for loop to set data values for elements in a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm currently trying to solve a fun computer games challenge I set myself, but I've hit a snag.

I intend to create a small game in which a player spawns at (1, 1) on a 10x10 tileset. This player must move using WASD, toward monsters which spawn randomly within the tileset. With each player movement, the monsters move one space in a random direction. When the player moves onto a monster, that monster is defeated.

Code so far:

```
using namespace std;

int tileset[10][10];                //Initializing 2D Array
int n = 10;                         //Initializing amount of turns to spawn enemy
int y = 0;                          //Initializing turn clock

class Square {
private:

public:

int squarePositionX, squarePositionY;
enum squareContents {BOTH , PLAYER , MONSTER , NONE};

};

int main() {

}
```

I'm currently trying to create a class to represent each square in the 2D array 'tileset', then use a for loop to use this class to initialize the x & y values for each square, but I'm not sure exactly how to do this.

Also, am I going about this task the entirely wrong way? This was a cool little challenge I set myself and I thought this was the best way to tackle it, but maybe I'm over-complicating it.

And assistance is greatly appreciated!
~Dean.

Comment: Some questions for you to think about:  Does the board contain `Square`s or integers?  Your posted code shows a `tileset` of integers.

Comment: The board, conceptually in my head, is 10x10 tiles, each with values for x co-ord, y co-ord and contents. That's what I'm trying desperately to incorporate. What is a more appropriate array type?

Comment: You want your board to be of type `Square`, as in `Square board[10][10];`

Comment: To modify square at 4,7, you would use `board[4][7].squarePositionX = -27;`

Comment: Ah, I understand much better now. Still getting to grips with classes. So (in this case) making a class 'Square' means I can use it as a data type?

Comment: All classes and structs are data types.

Comment: I get that now, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd make the game trivially simple at first and then augment the rules. Perhaps tic-tac-toe would be a better starting point?

Going with your game design, I'll try to keep it simple and give a few helpful suggestions since you are new.

This is a typical matrix (2D array) initialization.  The starting value may be a non-constant function of row and column indices i and j.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++ j) {
        tileset[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

If your enum is meant to be an enumeration of the possible values of tileset, then it is the enum type that the 2 dimensional array should be rather than int.

The initialization above might be done in the constructor of your class and may use something other than zero for your initialization value.  It may assign a function of i and j to the location for a starting game state.

Also, unless you want your member variables to be directly accessible from outside the class, you probably want them under the private section rather than the public.

Your main method will probably construct the game object (assuming "Square" is the name of it) and then call a method on the Game object like "simulatePlay()" or "makeMove(move)".

In more sophisticated games, you'd probably make SquareContents and Move separate classes from Square (again, assuming that is your game's name).

Comment: I recommend using `{` and `}` to show a newbie good coding practices. :-)

Comment: I've always used an Agile do-it-only-when-i-need-it philosophy with code grouping, Thomas, but I followed your recommendation out of respect and because I know I'm in the minority with that opinion. :)

Comment: Downvoter, perhaps you could give a newbie some grace? I think their effort qualifies as an initial try, and they may get quite a bit further with my answer above without much more interaction.

Comment: I'm struggling to set the array type as enum, getting an error saying 'expected an identifier' and 'expected a declaration.

Comment: I'm very new to using classes, so I'm sorry for the severe lack of knowledge, and I truly appreciate your patience. The for loop above, does this go in the public encapsulation of the Square class, or my main function?

How do I assign the x & y values to each array square, through the for loop?